# Google App Engine HRD Migration - Data Read Returns Nothing

Tags: google-app-engine, python-2.7

After following the instruction to migrate from a GAE app from Master/Slave to High Replication Datastore(HRD), the app is returning nothing for datastore read.  I am able to see the data using the "Datastore Viewer" and they are there (migrated successfully).  I have not changed any code.  Just wondering if there's anything I need to set or configure for the datastore read to happen.  I don't see any error in the "Log Console" on my dev machine and no error on the server's "Logs".

Comment: If you are able to see the data in the datastore viewer you should be able to be able to read them programatically. What is your old application id? What is your new application id? How do you access the datastore viewer? How do you access your application?

Comment: Datastore viewer is a tool provided GAE on the admin page of the GAE site.  After the migration, my app was loading (logo and general page element) but was just not displaying the simple text data from the datastore.  I checked the app again a day later and now the text data is showing so I assume it's something to do with GAE's migration.  btw, why the down vote?

Comment: Removed it now that you provided more context :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue has resolved itself after a few days.  Now the app is returning the correct data.  It may be just a glitch from the migration.  I have another GAE app that's stuck in the middle of the migration.  Searching on SO I have found others that are experiencing the same problem.